# Should "on point" and "spot on" be hyphenated in predicative position?

Tags: punctuation

Should "on point" and "spot on" be hyphenated in predicative position? I think the hyphen, in these cases, makes it clearer for the reader; do you agree with the hyphens in the four examples below?

He was spot-on.
He was spot-on with his advice.

He was on-point.
He was on-point with his advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but can find them in predicative position.

Comment: I emailed Kirk Mahoney, author of the book How to Use Hyphens. He said that both "on-point" and "spot-on" should be hyphenated in these examples, and I see why. He was spot-on. He was spot-on with his advice.

He was on-point. He was on-point with his advice. (Without the hyphens, the reader could be tripped up, even if for a nanosecond. Ex.: He was spot on with his advice. (He was spot) ((on with his advice)). I agree with him – not the dictionaries – with these.

Comment: The same with "ill-advised". He was ill advised – without the hyphen – could momentarily trip the reader into thinking "he was ill". Compare: He was ill advised VS. He was ill-advised. The reader instanteously grasps the meaning of the latter example because of the hyphen. Makes total sense. Many style guides say not to hyphenate words (in their predicative positions) after forms of the verb to-be. I disagree – to an extent.

Comment: I'd say that disambiguation should always trump so-called rules.

Answer (score 2):

There are some variations with both style and dictionary. I use *The Chicago Manual of Style* and *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* (and occasionally the unabridged). *Webster's* lists **spot-on** as a hyphenated word but not **on point**.

*He was spot-on.*

*He was spot-on with his advice.*

and *His spot-on advice ...*

*He was on point.*

*He was on point with his advice.*

but *His on-point advice ...*

Answer (score 0):

I would (without checking) have hyphenated them, **BUT:**

The Oxford On-Line dictionary has these entries:

**1.** Definition of **spot on** in English: adjective& adverb

Completely accurate or accurately:
[as adjective]: ‘**your reviews are spot on’**

**2.** Definition of **on point** in English: chiefly US Apposite; relevant:

‘his review of the album was **right on point’**

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know Oxford had an online dictionary. Very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: It's often useful for quick reference: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/